# reading numbers from one file, finding the fibonacci number of each number and writing the fibonacci number in a new file

Tags: c, file-io

Here's my code so far it compiles and runs but in the output file gives a large integer when only asking for the Fibonacci number of 0.

I believe the loop to find the fibonacci number is correct because i took copied the loop from another program i had that was functioning properly.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <ctype.h>
     #define SIZE 40

    int main(void)
 {
char ch, filename[SIZE]; //variables

int num;
int t1 = 0;
int t2 = 1;
int index;
int result;

FILE *fp;
printf("Please enter the filename to read: "); //asking for file that is to      be read
gets(filename);
// "r" reads the file fopen opens the file
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open the file, %s\n", filename);
}
else
{
    puts("Successfully opened, now reading.\n"); //reads through file  counting words, upper/lowercase letters, and digits.

     while ((num=getw(fp)) != EOF)
    {

    if(num == 1)        //if the nth term is 1
    result = 0;

    else if(num == 2)   //if the nth term is 2
    result = 1;

    else                //for loop to start at the 3rd term
    {
    for(index = 2; index <= num ; index++)
    {
    result = t1 + t2;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = result;
    }
    }
    }
}



fclose(fp); //closing the file

char filename2 [SIZE];
FILE *fp2;

fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the file name to write in: "); //asks for file that you want to write to
gets(filename2);

if ((fp2 = fopen(filename2, "w")) == NULL) //"w" for writing
{
    printf("Cannot create the file, %s\n", filename2);
}
else
{
    fprintf(fp2, "%d", result);


}

fclose(fp2); // closing the file
fprintf(stdout, "You are writing to the file, %s is done.\n", filename2);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: file in text mode used with getw, it's suspicious. Can you provide a sample of your input file? is it text/binary?

Comment: its a text file called input.in

Answer (score 1):

There may be other problems, but the biggest one is that you're using `getw`, which reads a binary integer from a file (like `fread` would do) but you're reading from a text file.

> getw() reads a word (that is, an int) from stream. It's provided for compatibility with SVr4. We recommend you use fread(3) instead.

So your input data is garbage, which probably explains the large integer you're getting.

I would replace:

```
while ((num=getw(fp)) != EOF)
```

by

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&num)==1)
```

So the number is read as *text*. And the reading stops when reaching a non-number or end of file.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `result` is not initialized and nowhere set if `num` is 0, so what you get from your program may as well be *a large integer* as something else.